# D3.js + CSS button functionality

Tags: css, d3.js

I have been toiling away at this one particular graph that is a modified bullet chart from one of Mike Bostock's templates. I wanted to enhance it with some button events, specifically: when you click a button it will call a transition animation to change the graph markers to new values. Both new and old values are provided in the code in raw data form. For clarity and context I have included the code in it's entirety. Search for my comment "//confusion below" to get to the part where I defined my button functions.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bullet Chart</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<style>
  body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  /*width: 100%;*/
}
table{
  width:60%;
  margin-left:auto; 
  margin-right:auto;
}
td{width:50%;}
.bulleT { font: 10px sans-serif; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
.bulleT .marker { stroke: #4D4D4D; stroke-width: 2px;}
.bulleT .marker.s0 { fill-opacity:0; stroke: #999999; stroke-width: 2px; }
.bulleT .marker.s1 { fill-opacity:0; stroke: #000; stroke-width: 2px; }
.bulleT .tick line { stroke: #666; stroke-width: .5px; }

.bulleT .range.s0 { fill: #005C7A; }
.bulleT .range.s1 { fill: #29A3CC; }
.bulleT .range.s2 { fill: #c6dbef; }
.bulleT .range.s3 { fill: #29A3CC; } 
.bulleT .range.s4 { fill: #005C7A; }

.bulleT .measure.s0 { fill: #4D4D4D; }
.bulleT .measure.s1 { fill: #999999; } 
.bulleT .measure.s2 { fill: #eeeeee; }
.bulleT .measure.s3 { fill: #999999; }
.bulleT .measure.s4 { fill: #4D4D4D; }

.bulleT .title { font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; }
.bulleT .subtitle.s04 { fill: #000000; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold;} 
.bulleT .subtitle.s13 { fill: #999999; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;}
.bulleT .subtitle.s2  { fill: #999999; font-size: 10px;}
  
.option {
 font-family: Play;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-size: 12px;
  width: 6%;
 background: #303030;
 padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
}

.option:hover {
 background: #4c4d4d;
}

div#option2{
  position:relative;
  top: 10px;
}

</style>
<body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="canvas-svg">
<div id="canvas-svg">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="BulleT_horizontal"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="option1" class="option"> Outcome 1</div>
<div id="option2" class="option"> Outcome 2</div>
<p>The Bullet Chart is here.</p>
<script>

(function() {
// Simple modification based on mbostock's Bullet Charts.
d3.bulleT = function() {
  var orient = "left",
      reverse = false,
      vertical = false,
      terjedelem = bulleTTerjedelem,
      ranges = bulleTRanges,
      markers = bulleTMarkers,
      measures = bulleTMeasures,
      width = 380,
      height = 30,
      tickFormat = null;

  // For each small multiple
  function bulleT(g) {
    g.each(function(d, i) {
      var terjedelemz = terjedelem.call(this, d, i),
          rangez = ranges.call(this, d, i).slice().sort(d3.descending),
          markerz = markers.call(this, d, i),
          measurez = measures.call(this, d, i).slice().sort(d3.descending),
          g = d3.select(this);

      var wrap = g.select("g.wrap");

      if (wrap.empty()) wrap = g.append("g").attr("class", "wrap");
      // Compute the x-scale.
      var x0 = d3.scale.linear()
          .domain([terjedelemz[0], terjedelemz[1]])
          .range(reverse ? [width, 0] : [0, width]);

      // Stash the new scale.
      this.__chart__ = x0;

      // Derive width-scales from the x-scales.
      var w = bulleTWidth(x0,terjedelemz[0]);

      // Update the range rects.
      rangez.unshift(terjedelemz[1]);
      var range = wrap.selectAll("rect.range")
          .data(rangez);
      range.enter().append("rect")
          .filter( function(d, i){ if(i != 3){ return d} })
          .attr("class", function(d, i) { return "range s" + i; })
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("y", 0)
          .attr("height",height)
          .attr("x", reverse ? x0 : 0);
      range.enter().append("line")
          .filter( function(d, i){ if(i == 3){ return d} })
          .attr("class", "marker")
          .attr("x1", x0)
          .attr("x2", x0)
          .attr("y1", 0)
          .attr("y2", height);

      // Append the measure rects.
      measurez.unshift(terjedelemz[1]);
      var measure = wrap.selectAll("rect.measure")
          .data(measurez);
      measure.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", function(d, i) { return "measure s" + i; })
          .attr("width", w)
          .attr("height", height / 2)
          .attr("x", reverse ? x0 : 0)
          .attr("y", height / 4);
      // Append rect and line marker.
      var marker = wrap.selectAll("rect.marker")
          .data(markerz);
      marker.enter().append("rect")
          .filter( function(d, i){ if(i == 1){ return d} })
          .attr("class", "marker s1")
          .attr("width", 6)
          .attr("y", -(height/10))
          .attr("height",function(d) {return height+(height/5);})
          .attr("x", x0)
          .attr("transform", "translate(-3,0)");
//confusion below
      var option1 = d3.select("#option1");
      option1.on('click.outcome', outcome1);
      //option1.on('click.val', val=[100,200,1000,20]);

      var option2 = d3.select("#option2");
      option2.on('click.outcome', outcome2);

      function outcome1(val) {
        d.markerz = [1000, 2000, 10, 20]
        d3.selectAll('rect.marker')
        .transition()
        .duration(3000)
        .attr("x", function(d) {return d})
      }

      function outcome2(val) {
        d.markerz = [-1000, -2000, -10, -20]
        d3.selectAll('rect.marker')
        .transition()
        .duration(3000)
        .attr("x", function(d) {return d})
      };

      marker.enter().append("line")
          .filter( function(d, i){ if(i == 0){ return d} })
          .attr("class", "marker s0")
          .attr("x1", x0)
          .attr("x2", x0)
          .attr("y1", height / 4)
          .attr("y2", height-(height / 4) );

      // Compute the tick format.
      var format = tickFormat || x0.tickFormat(8);

      // Update the tick groups.
      var tick = g.selectAll("tick")
          .data(x0.ticks(8), function(d) {
            return this.textContent || format(d);
          });

      // Initialize the ticks with the old scale, x0.
      var tickEnter = tick.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "tick")
          .attr("transform", bulleTTranslate(x0))
          .style("opacity", 1);

      tickEnter.append("line")
          .attr("y1", height)
          .attr("y2", height * 7 / 6);

      tickEnter.append("text")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("transform", function(d){
            if (vertical) {
              return "rotate(90)";
            }
          })
          .attr("dy",  function(d){
            if(vertical){return width/60; }else{ return height+15 }
          })
          .attr("dx",  function(d){
            if(vertical){return height+15 ;}
          })
          .text(format);
    });
  }

  // left, right, top, bottom
  bulleT.orient = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return orient;
    orient = x;
    reverse = orient == "right" || orient == "bottom";
    return bulleT;
  };

  // terjedelem
  bulleT.terjedelem = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return terjedelem;
    terjedelem = x;
    return bulleT;
  };

  // ranges (bad, satisfactory, good)
  bulleT.ranges = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return ranges;
    ranges = x;
    return bulleT;
  };
//*
  // markers (previous, goal)
  bulleT.markers = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return markers;
    markers = x;
    return bulleT;
  };

  // measures (actual, forecast)
  bulleT.measures = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return measures;
    measures = x;
    return bulleT;
  };
//*/
  bulleT.vertical = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return vertical;
    vertical = x;
    return bulleT;
  };
  bulleT.width = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return width;
    width = x;
    return bulleT;
  };

  bulleT.height = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return height;
    height = x;
    return bulleT;
  };

  bulleT.tickFormat = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) return tickFormat;
    tickFormat = x;
    return bulleT;
  };
  return bulleT;
};

function bulleTTerjedelem(d) {
  return d.terjedelem;
}

function bulleTRanges(d) {
  return d.ranges;
}

function bulleTMarkers(d) {
  return d.markers;
}

function bulleTMeasures(d) {
  return d.measures;
}

function bulleTTranslate(x) {
  return function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d) + ",0)";
  };
}

function bulleTWidth(x,y) {
  var x0 = x(0);
  return function(d) {
    return Math.abs(x(d-y) - x0);
  };
}

})();

var Tscore_Man_Height = -1019;
var Tscore_Woman_Height = -261;
var Tscore_Man_Weight = -4.64;
var Tscore_Woman_Weight = -1.6;

var Tscore2 = 1300
// terjedelem is the hungarian translation of the statistical term of range
var data = [
  {"title":"Exper","dimension":"(diff)","subtitle":Tscore_Man_Height,"terjedelem":[-3000,3000],"ranges":[ -2000, -1000, 0, 1000, 2000],"measures":[-1366,-676,605,1108.81],"markers":[-23,Tscore_Man_Height]},
  {"title":"Gold","dimension":"(diff)","subtitle":Tscore_Woman_Height,"terjedelem":[-8000,8000],"ranges":[-5250,-2750,0,2750,5250],"measures":[-901,110,845.5,2107.5],"markers":[412,Tscore_Woman_Height]},
  {"title":"Tech","dimension":"(diff)","subtitle":Tscore_Man_Weight,"terjedelem":[-20,20],"ranges":[-13.33,-6.66,0,6.66,13.33],"measures":[-8.7,-.9,4.9,10.7],"markers":[1,Tscore_Man_Weight]},
  {"title":"Units","dimension":"(diff)","subtitle":Tscore_Woman_Weight,"terjedelem":[-80,80],"ranges":[-53.33,-26.66,0,26.66,53.33],"measures":[-18,-7.8,3.8,23],"markers":[-3,Tscore_Woman_Weight]}
]
var Width = 400, Height = 50;

var margin = {top: 5, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 60},
    width = Width - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = Height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var chart = d3.bulleT()
    .width(width)
    .height(height);

function bulleT(whichData,whereToPut,direction) {
  var a=Width, b=Height;
  if( direction == "vertical"){
    Height=a;Width=b+30;
    vertical = true;
  }else{
    Height=a-20;Width=b;
    vertical = false;
  }

  var svg = d3.select(whereToPut).selectAll("svg")
      .data(whichData)
    .enter().append("svg")
      .attr("class", "bulleT")
      .attr("width", Width)
      .attr("height", Height)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(){
        if( direction == "vertical"){
          return "rotate(-90)translate("+ -(Height-margin.left) +",10)";
        }else{
          return "translate("+ margin.left +","+ margin.top +")";
        }
      })
      .call(chart.vertical(vertical));

  var title = svg.append("g")
      .style("text-anchor", function(){
        if( direction == "vertical"){
          return "middle";
        }else{
          return "end";
        }
      })
      .attr("transform", function(){
        if( direction == "vertical"){
          return "rotate(90)translate("+ Width/4 +",20)";
        }else{
          return "translate(-16," + height / 3 + ")";
        }
      });

  title.append("text")
      .attr("class", "title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.title; });

  title.append("text")
      .attr("dy", "1.2em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.dimension; })

  title.append("text")
      .attr("class",function(d) {
          switch (true)
          {
            case ( (d.markers[1] < 30) || (70 < d.markers[1]) ):
              return "subtitle s04";
              break;
              break;
            case ( (30 <= d.markers[1]) && (d.markers[1] < 40) ):
              return "subtitle s13";
              break;
            case ( (40 <= d.markers[1]) && (d.markers[1] <= 60) ):
              return "subtitle s2";
              break;
            case ( (60 < d.markers[1]) && (d.markers[1] <= 70) ):
              return "subtitle s13";
              break;
          }
        }
      )
      .attr("dy", function(){
        return "2.4em";
      })
      .text(function(d) { return d.subtitle; });
};


bulleT(data,"#BulleT_vertical","vertical");  // "horizontal" or "vertical"
bulleT(data,"#BulleT_horizontal","horizontal");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the buttons, they both do the same thing, even though I changed markerz to different values. Moreover, they don't even do the right thing, the values seem to be wrong as some of the markers go flying off the graph boundary. So whatever I'm doing doesn't seem to change the way the data is parsed. Also, I'm not entirely sure that this raw value data would be scaled to go with the x scale of the graph, or if I need to scale it again as it goes through my button functions. The scaling seems to have something to do with x0 in the code above. I couldn't get it to work with my button for some reason.

There is a similar updated block here that has functional button functionality:

http://bl.ocks.org/CodeXmonk/6187523

My graph is different in that I don't change the measures or anything other than where the markers are positioned. And I'm not randomizing the data, I have pre-coded raw data that I want to switch back and forth from using my css buttons.

So what I'm looking for is how I can code the buttons to work with pre-existing scales and load raw data and put it into the markerz, or some other variable for the .transition() animation. That way the buttons will have the desired effect of moving the markers across the graph.

Sorry I couldn't make this shorter. I hope this will be worth everyone's while though because d3.js + css interface is a really powerful combination. I hope we can all learn from this example.

Thank you for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further toiling, I have good news. I got it working by pure trial and error. I will post a partial answer here. I managed to get a functional chart in terms of using .transition() with precoded raw data in pixel form. Note: the only way I got this to work was by putting in the pixel value of x for the transition. Ideally, I'd like to just put in the raw data (in data form) and have the existing scale handle it to automatically compute the pixel values. I'm not going to be too picky for now. Here is what I have going so far. I took the trouble to post my own gist, because I want it to be easier to view than the lengthy code above.

https://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/83188e161c39f2d0f7025087598ec075

I still need an answer on the following:

1. how to leverage existing scales alongside my raw data that is coupled with my css button functions
2. How do I update the subtitle text? It doesn't know I updated the values so they always read "1153, 1506, 8.63, 5.86". Ideally when I click Outcome 1, I want them to reflect the new marker positions: "-1019,-261,-4.64,-1.6". Then still be able to revert back to "1153, 1506, 8.63, 5.86" upon clicking the Outcome 2 button.

With regards to 2., I tried copying and pasting the title.append snippet for the marker values and using another mouse event for the cue, but each way I did it returned an error. Any experienced d3 people know how to do that?

Lastly, I'm not sure why, but every time I click a button, the dev tool error count increases by 1. The error is, "something something is not a function". I'm guessing that's not a good sign. However, the graph does work for the most part. I don't know how much I should be freaking out about these errors.

Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use document.ready function for each variable and then give the .on click function.